# ES: Поиск некоторых uuid в поле с массивом uuid'ов

Tags: elasticsearch

Не могу понять почему не ищет...

Имея на руках список брендов, пытаюсь найти товары у которых встречается хотя бы один из них.

Elastic версии 2.3.2

Пример записи

```
  {
   "_index": "xxx",
   "_type": "item",
   "_id": "77a9d1b0-31d8-4426-8751-6e544029031b",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "item": "Item name",
      "brands": [
         "756ce796-8cb3-4cda-8a0e-3660a56d4928"
      ],
   }
  }
```

Пытаюсь вот таким запросом достать все итемы с хотя бы одним брендом из массива

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/xxx/item/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
               {
                  "terms": {
                     "brands": [
                        "6c28d3fe-c8ab-4aee-88bf-eff7a7acfc6b",
                        "2646f9c7-31a1-4f6b-a039-633fdd9629dfc",
                        "a0bad100-1876-448d-9017-62a015a28d24",
                        "26463bfe-c937-4051-8a0f-2c3e5f025cb2",
                        "756ce796-8cb3-4cda-8a0e-3660a56d4928",
                        "afd76352-ca21-47d5-8236-4fb54cfbf6f8"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
      }
   }
}'
```

В ответ ничего не находит

Comment: Я так понял токенайзер разбил мой uuid на 5 слов...

Answer (score 0):

В общем UUID разбивался на 5 слов через тире.
Что б всё стало хорошо нужно в меппинге полю проставить `brands: { type: string, index: "not_analyzed" }`